# Boost: How to use \\+ in C POSIX regex interface

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

I am trying to use BOOST.Regex POSIX Compatible C API's. I am using `regcomp()` to match an expression like `a\+`, which should match `aa` and `aaa`, while using `cflags=REG_BASIC`. I have `regcomp( reg, "a\\+", REG_BASIC)` but it is not working.

I found a [link](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) stating that `\+`  is not  part of the POSIX standard. But I found in [Boost POSIX Basic regular expression documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/basic_syntax.html#boost_regex.posix_basic) an Emacs variation that supports `\+` syntax.

How can I use `\+` in POSIX Basic Regular Expressions? Or in other words, enable Emacs variation.

References:

- [POSIX Compatible C API's](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/posix.html)
- [POSIX Basic Regular Expressions](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/basic_syntax.html#boost_regex.posix_basic)
- [Options for POSIX Basic Regular Expressions](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/syntax_option_type/syntax_option_type_basic.html)

Comment: You do not need the `+` quantifier since you may use `\{1,\}`. `\+` is an extension for some POSIX regex implementations (as in GNU sed), and is not portable.

Comment: Well, if you plan to use `emacs` "flavor", use `boost::regex::emacs` and enjoy `+`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Actually I am using the POSIX Compatible C API's as the APIs are called from c code. Is there a way to use `boost::regex::emacs`  from  c code?

Comment: It seems you need `REG_EXTENDED` rather than `REG_BASIC` then.